# MySQL: How to get TOP visited product for each user in a table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a system with products. Everytime a user enters a product, I insert a record into my database.

I have a table with users and id_products, like this:

```
users           id_product
____________________________
jondoe               2
george               9
jondoe               5
jondoe               2
george               9
george               9
george               2
```

I need a result (query) wich shows what is TOP visited product id for each user, so the result would be something like this:

```
jondoes most visited product is ID 2
georges most visitedproduct is ID 9
```

I was looking for the answer but I am not able to figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it a lot.

Jan

Comment: Does `Select * from table GROUP BY users` not work appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain because it involves aggregation.  One way to solve this uses a very complicated query.  Another uses variables.  A third method uses an aggregation trick that works under many circumstances:

```
select user,
       substring_index(group_concat(id_product order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as mostCommonProduct
from (select user, id_product, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by user, id_product
     ) t
group by user;
```

One danger when using this method is that the intermediate result might be too long.  You can set the `group_concat_max_len` system variable to get around that particular problem.